# how to test a method of models with rspec and factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I'm newbie on rails and I have to write tests for existing rails apps with 'Rspec','shoulda' and 'factory girl' gems. I can test non specific tests like validates_presence_of: something with 'sholda' matchers. But I want to test methods which in models. I can visualize what I need to do, but I can't compose.

This is an example what I'm talking about:

```
.
.
.
context 'is editable if project is not started' do
  setup do
    @brief=Factory(:brief)
    @started_project=Factory(:project_started, :brief => @brief)
    @brief_have_no_project=Factory(:brief)
  end
  specify "with editable brief" do
    @brief.brand_info = 'bla bla bla' #change brand info, this is impossible
    #i can't compose this section :S
  end
  specify "with non-editable brief" do

  end
end

.
.
.
```

I want to test is brief editable in this code. How can I test it?

This is the brief models code:

```
class Brief < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  validate :can_only_be_edited_if_project_is_not_started

  .
  .
  .

  def can_only_be_edited_if_project_is_not_started
    errors.add(:project_id, 'can_only_be_edited_if_project_is_not_started') if
      !project.nil? && !project.brief_can_be_edited?
  end

  .
  .
  .

end
```

I will be very happy if I can find a starting point. Thanks for help. :)

Failures:

1) Brief is editable if project is not started with editable brief.

```
Failure/Error: @brief.brand_info = 'bla bla bla'
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `brand_info=' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/models/brief_spec.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

when try to assign value like this @brief.brand_info = 'bla bla bla'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem by myself.

```
it "with editable brief (not started project)" do
  brief=Factory.build(:brief)
  Factory(:project, :brief => brief)
  brief.should have(0).error_on(:project_id)
end
it "with editable brief (nil project)" do
  brief=Factory.build(:brief)
  brief.brand_info="bla bla bla"
  brief.should have(0).error_on(:project_id)
end
it "with non-editable brief" do
  brief=Factory.build(:brief)
  Factory(:project_started, :brief => brief)
  brief.should have(1).error_on(:project_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is saved:

```
@brief.save.should be_true
```

Saving forces validation. If validation fails, save doesn't occur, in which case it returns false.